# How to edit Debian installer boot paramaters?

Tags: boot, debian-installer

I need to edit the boot parameters of the Debian installer to add `priority=critical` to the arguments. (this is for [preseeding](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed)). What should I do to apply these parameters to the installer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which architecture (i386, amd64, etc.), which media (CD/DVD/BD, USB-HDD, netboot, etc.), which release (jessie, wheezy, etc.), or which firmware (BIOS, UEFI, etc.) you want to boot to run Debian Installer.

For Debian jessie ISO images for Intel PC BIOS based architecture, you will use [isolinux](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/ISOLINUX) boot loader.  You can find menu entry `auto` in `/isolinux/adtxt.cfg` which you should choose for preseeding installation:

```
label auto
    menu label ^Automated install
    kernel /install.amd/vmlinuz
    append auto=true priority=critical vga=788 initrd=/install.amd/initrd.gz --- quiet
```

You can also configure default entry to boot and time out value in `/isolinux/isolinux.cfg`:

```
# D-I config version 2.0
# search path for the c32 support libraries (libcom32, libutil etc.)
path 
include menu.cfg
default vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 0
```

For example it will start preseeding installation automatically after 10 sec delay on boot by the following configuration.

```
default auto
prompt 1
timeout 100 # in units of 0.1 sec
```

Take care not to accidentally start the installer on existing installed systems.  It would wipe everything on them automatically!